# Как посчитать количество пользователей за каждый месяц?

Tags: sql, аналитика

Вопрос по SQL. Понимаю, что это не тот форум, где активно обсуждают SQL, но у меня кончились мысли. Вопрос такой. Есть таблица - в ней два поля - user_id и time (тут хранится дата - год и месяц). Надо посчитать, сколько НОВЫХ пользователей в каждом месяце. Буду благодарен идеям.

Comment: *Есть таблица - в ней два поля - user_id и time (тут хранится дата - год и месяц).* Во-первых, структуру таблицы дают как её CREATE TABLE скрипт (ещё лучше, если к нему добавить INSERT INTO скрипт с примером данных, 2-3 записи хотя бы), а не словесным описанием. Во-вторых, год и месяц - это ни фига не дата. В третьих, укажите ТОЧНО используемую СУБД и её версию.

Comment: *Понимаю, что это не тот форум, где активно обсуждают SQL* - здесь обсуждают все, что имеет отношение к программированию. SQL в том числе. Здесь есть пара очень компетентных человек в этой области. @Akina - одна из них.

Comment: Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Comment: @cauf Не, мне, конечно, как бы пофиг... но вот так огульно выносить меня в дамскую половину не стОит...

Comment: @Akina кмк, ни раз встречал обращение к вам, как к человеку женского пола, не?